# Is there any way to evaluate this limit without applying de l'Hôpital rule nor series expansion?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is there a way to evaluate this limit:

$$\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{\sin(e^{\tan^2 x} - 1)}{\cos^{\frac35}(x) - \cos(x)}$$

without using de l'Hôpital rule and series expansion?

Thank you,

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to avoid those tools?

Comment: Using $\lim_{x\to O}\frac{\sin x}x=1$ we have to compute $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\tan^2x}-1}x$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-(\cos x)^{2/5}}x$. We we know the derivatives of the involved functions.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Just out of curiosity, I want to know whether it can be solved in another way.

Comment: You could also further eliminate trig functions from consideration with the substitution $x=\arctan y$, so $\tan x=y$ and $\cos x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y^2}}$.

Comment: "solve" is the wrong word.  "Evaluate" is the right word.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Didn't know that, as I'm not a native English speaker, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should know the following limits:
$$\begin{split}\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\sin y}{y} &= 1\\ \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{e^y-1}{y} &= 1\\ \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{\tan y}{ y} &= 1\\ \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{(1+y)^\theta -1}{y} &= \theta \qquad \text{(}\forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}\text{)}\\
\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{1-\cos y}{y^2} &= \frac{1}{2}\end{split}$$
which can be proved using only elementary Calculus tools (i.e. **without** any Differential Calculus technique).
These five limits are usually written as *asymptotic relations* in the following manner:
$$\tag{1} \sin y \approx y$$
$$\tag{2} e^y-1 \approx y$$
$$\tag{3} \tan y \approx y$$
$$\tag{4} (1+y)^\theta -1 \approx \theta\ y$$
$$\tag{5} 1-\cos y \approx \frac{1}{2}\ y^2$$
as $y\to 0$. Using asymptotics (**1**) - (**5**) you find:
$$\begin{split} \sin(e^{\tan^ 2 x} - 1) &\approx e^{\tan^2 x}-1 &\quad \text{by (1)}\\
&\approx \tan^2 x &\quad \text{by (2)}\\
&\approx x^2  &\quad \text{by (3)}\end{split}$$
$$\begin{split}\cos^{3/5}(x) - \cos(x) &= \Big(\big(1+(\cos x-1)\big)^{3/5} -1\Big) + \Big(1-\cos x\Big)\\ &\approx \frac{3}{5}\ (\cos x-1) + (1-\cos x) &\text{by (4) with } \theta =3/5\\
&= \frac{2}{5}\ (1-\cos x)\\
&\approx \frac{1}{5}\ x^2 &\text{by (5)}\end{split}$$
hence:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(e^{\tan ^ 2 {x}} - 1)}{\cos^{\frac{3}{5}}(x) - \cos(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x^2}{\frac{1}{5}\ x^2}=5\; .$$

Comment: Wow! Great! Thank you very much for your comprehensive reply.

Comment: While your approach is correct, I would have avoided the use of $\approx$ symbol. Limit evaluations are an exact thing and hence it is better not to use "asymptotics" as a shorthand of usual rules of limits.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer... I miss your point here.

I used *asymptotics* just as shorthands for $\sin y = y + \text{o}(y)$, $\tan y = y + \text{o}(y)$, $e^y - 1 = y+\text{o}(y)$, $1-\cos y = \frac{1}{2}y^2 + \text{o}(y^2)$ and $(1+y)^\theta = \theta y + \text{o}(y)$ respectively.
Any other asymptotic expansion I used can also be evaluated from these relations, using the usual algebraic rules for Landau symbol $\text{o}$... Nevertheless, calculations of this type are ususally lengthy and tedious, so I try to skip them as soon as I can. ;-D

Answer (score 6):

This is similar to the accepted answer by user Pacciu, but avoids the use of "asymptotics" and $\approx$ symbols as these are totally unnecessary and perhaps can be confusing to a beginner. Rules of limits combined with the following standard limits is sufficient: $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1,\,\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{x} - 1}{x} = 1,\,\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1 - \cos x}{x^{2}} = \frac{1}{2},\,\lim_{x \to a}\frac{x^{n} - a^{n}}{x - a} = na^{n - 1}$$ where $n$ is rational.

We can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(e^{\tan^{2}x} - 1)}{\cos^{3/5}x - \cos x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(e^{\tan^{2}x} - 1)}{e^{\tan^{2}x} - 1}\cdot\frac{e^{\tan^{2}x} - 1}{\cos^{3/5}x - \cos x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{\tan^{2}x} - 1}{\cos^{3/5}x - \cos x}\text{ (putting }t = e^{\tan^{2}x} - 1)\notag\\
&= 1\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{\tan^{2}x} - 1}{\tan^{2}x}\cdot\frac{\tan^{2}x}{\cos^{3/5}x - \cos x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{e^{t} - 1}{t}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\tan^{2}x}{\cos^{3/5}x - \cos x}\text{ (putting }t = \tan^{2}x)\notag\\
&= 1\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{\cos^{2}x}\cdot\frac{1}{\cos^{3/5}x - \cos x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{1\cdot\{\cos^{3/5}x - \cos x\}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{2}x}{x^{2}}\cdot\frac{x^{2}}{\cos^{3/5}x - \cos x}\notag\\
&= 1\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{2}}{(1 - \cos x) - (1 - \cos^{3/5}x)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^{2}}{(1 - \cos x)}\cdot\dfrac{1}{1 - \dfrac{1 - \cos^{3/5}x}{1 - \cos x}}\notag\\
&= 2\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{1}{1 - \dfrac{\cos^{3/5}x - 1}{\cos x - 1}}\notag\\
&= 2\lim_{t \to 1}\dfrac{1}{1 - \dfrac{t^{3/5} - 1}{t - 1}}\text{ (putting }t = \cos x)\notag\\
&= 2\cdot\dfrac{1}{1 - \dfrac{3}{5}} \text{ (here }n = 3/5, a = 1)\notag\\
&= 5\notag
\end{align}

Comment: Wow, so many algebraic steps! Did you just go by trial and error or already know the steps?

Comment: @rubik: Well its a fairly standard technique which I use in almost all limits problems which I solve on this website. You just need to keep on manipulating expressions so that you can make use of standard limits. For example, if you see an expression like $\sin(\dots)$ and argument of $\sin$ tends to $0$ simply divide and multiply this by the argument. This way we make use of $(\sin x)/x \to 1$ and after this step $\sin$ function is gone from the expression. If you see expr like $e^{\dots} - 1$ where exponent of $e$ tends to $0$ again mul and div and then $e$ is gone. Continued ...

Comment: @rubik: And if you see $\log(\dots)$ and its argument tends to $1$ then express it as $\log(1 + \cdots)$ where $\cdots \to 0$ and mul and div by $\cdots$ and log function is gone. Finally you are left with nothing but simple algebra of actual constants like $1, 2, 3, 5$ and you are done.

Comment: Right, well explained!

Comment: ""If you see expr like e…−1 where exponent of e tends to 0 again mul and div and then e is gone.""multiply n divide by what? Sir

Comment: Did it mean the standards limit: lim x→0 ($\frac{e^x-1}{x}$)=1

Comment: @SathasivamK: yes I was talking about that limit. And we have to mul and div by exponent of $e$.

Comment: +1 for the use of the last limit, which reduce the least convenient part of the original limit to a limit computed using basic algebra, "short multiplication formulas"

Answer (score 1):

You can write

$$\sin(e^{\tan^2 x}-1)={\sin(e^{\tan^2 x}-1)\over e^{\tan^2 x}-1}\cdot {e^{\tan^2 x}-1 \over \tan^2 x}\cdot {\tan^2 x\over x^2} x^2=:  g(x)\ x^2$$

with $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=1$, but I don't see a similar expansion of the denominator without using somehow that $(1+u)^{3/5}\sim 1+{3\over 5}u$ for $u\to 0$.